# How to create a rule in Outlook 2010 to move all emails from an IMAP sent folder to local sent folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, imap, pst, email-filter

How can I create a rule in Outlook 2010 to move all emails from an IMAP sent folder to a local sent folder?

So far the closest I've been able to get is to move all emails from the IMAP *inbox* to the local inbox- but now I want to grab all the emails from the sent folder also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is NOT to start from the **Create Rule...** drop down link. Instead choose **Manage Rules and Alerts** option and click **New Rule...**.

You should then have the option to create a new rule based on **Apply rule on messages I send**.

[image: Rules]